# Serializing objects as raw memory

Tags: performance, serialization

It seems that if it were possible to serialize data as the raw memory chunks that properties and fields are made up of, then it ought to be that much faster to communicate these objects to another system and the other system would only have to allocate memory for this memory and properly set reference pointers where they should go.

Yes, I know that's a little oversimplified and there are probably a plethora of reasons why it's difficult to do (like circular references).  But I'm wondering if anyone has tried it and if there is a way to do it possibly with objects that meet certain restrictions?

One the one hand this is probably me just trying to micro-optimize, but on the other hand it really seems like this could be pretty useful in certain scenarios where performance is vital.

Comment: I think memory-mapped network communication like you describe is actually fairly common-place. If all your machines have the same hardware and the same binaries, it's pretty feasible.

Comment: @KerrekSB Is that something that requires special hardware and do you have any recommendations for further reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously this kind of serialization is going to be faster than JSON any day (XML is slow by definition. In fact, I think that's what the L stands for. It was supposed to be XMS, but because it's so slow they missed the S and ended up with an L). However, I doubt it would beat efficient binary serializations such as Google's Protocol Buffers in real world scenarios.

If your serialized entities hold no references to other entities, *and* your memory layout on the two sides is exactly the same (same alignment, same order, etc...), you'll earn a little bit of performance by copying the memory buffer once, instead of doing so in chunks. However, the second  you have to reconstruct references, memory copying is going to be trivial compared to looking up the referenced object. Copying memory is *fast*, especially when done in order, minimizing cache misses.

Comment: So you would say that if references have to be reconstructed that the performance gain would be so minimal as to be practically insignificant?

Comment: I think the raw memory addresses will be absolute.  You wouldn't be able to simply copy a range and pluck it down somewhere else without having to adjust pointers (unless I'm missing something).  However if you have the data sitting in shared memory multiple processes can map to it and see it.  I wouldn't call this 'serialization' though.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm saying. Unless perhaps you have huge structures with very few entities, but that doesn't happen usually.

Answer (score 0):

Things like normal memory addresses will completely break between serialization-deserialization.  However if you're clever and careful you could device a mechanism where a data structure is serialized.  Maybe translate addresses to offset-bytes-from-base?

Comment: In the case of a struct with a sequential layout that probably wouldn't even be necessary, but for anything else the data could be spread out all over the place so I don't know if that would be practical.  I was thinking more along the lines of somehow communicating what chunks of data belong to which properties and letting the client reconstruct references with new pointers.  According to zmbq it sounds like that might negate the benefits though.